# .Net Core 3 (on Mac OS Mojave) -> Why is System.IO prepending provided path with solution path?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

If I run the following line:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("\\\\myNetworkShare\\myfile.txt")
```

I get a exception saying that the path "/Users/Me/{SolutionPath}\myNetworkShare\myfile.txt" cannot be found...

Looking at the stack trace for the exception I found this:`at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode` which I believe is weird because im not on a windows environment (Mac OS Mojave)

I've also tried to change the protocol to SMB but the result is the same: apparently .NET is prepending the local solution path to the path I provide, despite it being a complete (and valid) path...

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Details:
Local env is MAC OSX Mojave
Fully Updated
Network share is provided by Windows Server

Comment: Mac uses a different directory separator. That's probably where the confusion comes in. I haven't used ASP.NET Core on a Mac, but have you tried something like `smb://myNetworkShare/myfile.txt` or `//myNetworkShare/myfile.txt`?

Comment: yes I did that also...

Comment: you have to get the volume path (i.e. from `/Volumes`). `SafeFileHandle` is just carry over from the .net framework, nothing suspect there. the path you've provided is a relative one to the mac file system.

Comment: @DanielA.White when I deploy the app on kubernets (using Debian based image) will I have to do that?

Comment: it depends how and where you mount the volume/share.

Comment: @DanielA.White it seems that you're correct. You have to access it via `/Volumes`. Any chance you know how to map a volume programmatically?

Comment: Could you have it as a user configure option?

Comment: @DanielA.White no... this is supposed to work "on the fly" where the user will provide a previously know network share and the API is supposed to connect and do its magic