# .Net Core 3 -> How to map network share in Unix based OS's?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

This is a fallback from [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977436/net-core-3-on-mac-os-mojave-why-is-system-io-prepending-provided-path-with).

At least for Mac OSX, you have to map the network in advance, and not only try reading from "\\myNetworkShare" which works on windows.

Now the question is: having a network path and a set of credentials, how can you programmatically map a network share using .Net Core 3, specifically for Unix based OS's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do so. You have to start a new process running `mount_smbfs` like:

```
var command = $"mount_smbfs //{username}:{password}@{uriPath.Host + uriPath.PathAndQuery} {myLocalFolder}";
var process = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", $"-c \"{command}\"");
process.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.CreateNoWindow = true;
return process;
```

It's important to notice that `myLocalFolder` must already exists AND not be already mounted, otherwise it will fail.